# error al intentar leer datos de la base de datos (Connection must be valid and open). C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Lo que me gustaria hacer es poder leer registro por registro conforme vaya avanzado el llenado de mi tabla, solamente para poder extraer el registro que yo quiera en el momento que quiera, agregue para eso un reader de Mysql, pero no se porque motivo me marca el siguient error:

> Connection must be valid and open.

Codigo de Conexion

```
        server = "localhost";
        database = "presupuesto";
      uid = "root";
        password = "";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
       connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);


       string Query = "select Id_Compra,Articulo,Categoria,Obligatorio,Costo,Adquirir from compra";
       MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
       MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2); 
       //For offline connection we weill use  MySqlDataAdapter class.  
       MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
       MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;
       DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
```

Codigo de Lectura.

```
if (this.connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
           {
               this.connection.Open();
               MySqlDataReader rdr = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
               while (rdr.Read())
               {
                   for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(x), "Inidce", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                   }

               }
           }
```

Comment: Estas seguro que el error ocurre en esa sentencia de código?

Comment: si, mas precisamente en donde se ejecuta el Reader (MyCommand2.ExecuteReader)

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar un poco mas de código? no me queda claro cómo estás inicializando la conexión; además, ¿cuál es el estado de `MyCommand2`?

Comment: Parece que estas usando un conexión que ya esta cerrada. Cuando vayas a abrir la conexión no utilices ´this.connection.open()´. Intenta creando un nueva Instancia de la Conexión con la instrucción using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion)).

Comment: ya actualice @Mauricio

Comment: @David, revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4233208/4092887) o también puedes intentar buscando: `C# Connection must be valid and open`. Suerte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    MyConn2.Open();
    MySqlDataReader rdr = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
         //Codigo que deseas usar en el reader
    }
    MyConn2.Close();
```

En tu codigo el DataReader rdr tiene asiganada la conexion MyConn2 y depende de que esta este abierta para realizar la consulta sobre la base de datos, en el bloque de codigo que proporcionas no encuentro nada que indique que:

```
    this.connection
```

Sea una conexion valida e instanciada

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar esos problemas de conexion puede hacerlos de la siguiente forma...

```
       using(MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)){
                 MyConn2.Open();
                 MySqlDataReader rdr = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
                 while (rdr.Read())
                 {
                      for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                      {
                             MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(x), "Inidce", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                      }

                 }
                 rdr.Close();
       }
```

Con esto te evitas problemas de tener conexiones abiertas y no poder abrir otras